# tkinter list and scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter

Lately I am using tkinter to make a GUI and using a list and a scrollbar. 
So far I have the following

```
scrollbar-Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGTH, fill=Y)
mylist=Listbox(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
mylist.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
scrollbar.config(command=mylist.yview)
```

that works well, but since the rest of my widgets use grid and not pack to place it, I would like to use grid and replace the packs above.

However I haven't found any example with grid.

Can someone give me an example??

My geometry is some sliders on the left and I want to place this listbox on the right

Comment: Why do you need an example? Have you tried using grid? The use of grid is covered in every tkinter tutorial, and there are thousands of questions on this site that use grid.

Comment: If you actual tried to [google tkinter grid() examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=tkinter+grid%28%29+examples&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) you would have found countless links. I think you put little effort into finding examples as many many many post here on stack overflow use `grid()` and many more on the internet. Not to mention there is clear [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) on the use of grid on the net as well.

Comment: i did indeed use grid. the result was that the scrollbar does indeed scrolls but it is minimized. also the list ocuppies only one cell no matter if i put rowspan to 2 or more. in conclusion ugly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code I asked. (Hope it serves someone with the same problem as me- I like to be useful :) )

```
scrollbar= Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.grid(row-1,column=3, rowspan=5, sticky=N+S)
mylist=Listbox(root, height=17, width=25, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
mylist.grid(row=1,column=2,rowspan=5,sticky=E+W)
scrollbar.config(command=mylist.yvies)
```

the key was the "sticky" part.